# Use axios instead of fetch requests in Workbox

Tags: vue.js, axios, workbox

Im trying to use workbox to save in cache some stuff for my project, I have already made it to save all my js and css files, fonts, etc, there's one thing missing and that is my project's content that is stored in my pc, Im using axios to fetch my database data, workbox seems to ignore the requests sent from axios, I have made a test and changed one axios request to "fetch" and it worked, it was successfully cached, theres any way to make it work using axios?

This is my code:

```
importScripts("https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.0/workbox-sw.js");

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('http://localhost/Odr/connections/'),
  workbox.strategies.cacheFirst(),
);
```

Comment: Sounds like Workbox has hooks added to the Fetch API but not `XMLHttpRequest` which is what Axios uses

Comment: Is there anything I can do? :c
Or should I start changing every axios request in my code?

Comment: You could switch to an Axios implementation that uses `fetch`. They exist but I can't recommend any as I've never used them

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing specific about `axios` that should prevent its requests from being intercepted by Workbox, or in general, from triggering the `fetch` handler inside of a service worker. `XMLHttpRequest`s made from client pages do result in the `fetch` handler being fired.

I would recommend using a [debug build](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/troubleshoot-and-debug#use_a_debug_build) of Workbox (which is the default if you're developing on `http://localhost`) and then opening the JavaScript console when you attempt your `axios` request. There are debugging messages that should shed light on Workbox's routing logic, including whether a particular request triggering a route or not.